# Multiple pdf invoice download restricted to 3 x 200 in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf

I am trying to download multiple invoices in pdf format and can successfully download 3 consecutive batches of 200 invoices.
Any subsequent attempts generate an error. I have tried downloading just 10 at a time to no avail. I can download them singly. 
If I use a different user, I can achieve exactly the same thing but no more, even if i attempt to down load invoices 601 >800 as a first print option.

The error log record is as follows:

> cat:
>   /var/www/vhosts/magento.domainname.co.uk/httpdocs/var/report/1385309872091:
>   Permission denied filemng: Error occurred during /bin/cat command.

and after renaming local.xml.sample get the following:
here has been an error processing your request
The requested Payment Method is not available.

Trace:

```
#0 /var/www/vhosts/magento.domainname.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php(82): Mage::throwException('The requested P...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/magento.domainname.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Helper/Data.php(119): Mage_Payment_Model_Info->getMethodInstance()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/magento.domainname.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php(316): Mage_Payment_Helper_Data->getInfoBlock(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/magento.domainname.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php(131): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract->insertOrder(Object(Zend_Pdf_Page), Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order), true)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/magento.domainname.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php(137): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice->getPdf(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Invoice_Collection))
#5 /var/www/vhosts/magento.domainname.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice->pdfinvoicesAction()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/magento.domainname.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('pdfinvoices')
#7 /var/www/vhosts/magento.domainname.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /var/www/vhosts/magento.domainname.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/magento.domainname.co.uk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/magento.domainname.co.uk/httpdocs/index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have cleared the var/cache.